# Can I get URL through NSURLResponse?

Tags: ios, cocoa

I have one url and using the viglink api i created other one, now using viglink api I want to get the URL, if i am getting the response.

```
  NSString *vigLinkApiKey = @"somekey";
        NSString *url = self.textfieldProductURL.stringValue;
        NSString *affiliatedUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.viglink.com/api/click?key=%@&out=%@&loc=http://amazon.com[&cuid=%@][&reaf=0][&ref=http://amazon.com]", vigLinkApiKey, url, [PFUser currentUser].username];

        NSLog(@"Product URL: %@", url);

        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:affiliatedUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30];

        NSData *urlData;
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *error;

        // Make synchronous request
        urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                        returningResponse:&response
                                                    error:&error];
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"str:%@",str);
```

Now, at last i want to get the URL when i am getting response. Is it possible. How can can i get the URL?

Please send the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read NSURLResponse documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NSURLResponse` has a method `- URL` use it to get URL.

```
NSURL *url = [response URL];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLResponse/URL